# How to clean this volume control? Which deoxit cleaner should i use?

Tags: cleaning

Of all the contact cleaners deoxit offers, i'm not sure if i should use D series or faderlube. (Note: This is NOT a volume control of the newer ones that just sends a signal to the software, this one actually controls the volume)

Thank you

[image: top view]

Answer (score 2):

I've always used Servisol Super 10 Switch Contact Cleaner on potentiometers.

Squirt it under the pot' or through a hole in it and wind the pot' backwards and forwards over full travel vigorously ten times or so. Repeat, let it evaporate off the board and voila - no crackles and all happy.

Comment: Interesting. Would you recommend this method for cleaning a vintage high current rheostat? I have some of them in my lab that may benefit from this, as they don't work too well right now.

Comment: Hi @EnricBlanco, someone told me this idea in college and I used in indiscriminately on hi-fi, TV and anything else with a cracking pot' until they died out in favour of menus, up/down switches and audio processing. Never had a bad result with it, always worked great :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the product you mention seems to be available in the UK. My question is which of the Deoxit products is the better one in this specific instance: Faderlube or D series?